# Array printing out multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to print out numbered links to search results.

If there are 5 pages in total, I only want 5 links showing, if there are 6 only 6 links etc. Only 10 links can display at a time.

Below I am setting the value to be 5 pages of search results(later I will load this number in from another part of the application). How do I print out the number of links based on the value of 'allPages'?

'smallPages' is in there for when I will later append '>' if there are more than 10 pages of search results

```
function updatePage() {
            var allPages = 5;
            var smallPages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

            if (allPages <= 10) {
                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    jQuery.each(allPages, function (index, value) {
                        $('#pages').append("<a href='#'>  " + value + '</a>');
                    })
                }
            }
```

Comment: Remove your for statement OR the `jQuery.each` function. You're nesting two iterations over the same array.

Comment: And even if you kept it in you'd be looping over a single variable rather than an array or object.

Comment: With    for (var i = 1; i < allPages; i++){$('#pages').append("<a href='#'>  " + allPages + '</a>');}   I only get the number 5 printed out 4 times

Comment: This shouldn't do anything at all.  `jQuery.each(5, ...` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm confused, but something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JxNu5/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes lots of confusing looping and checking going on. I would do a single for loop structured like the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < smallPages.length && i < allPages; i++)
    $('#pages').append("<a href='#'> " + smallPages[i] + '</a>');
```

This will check that you don't run over the end of smallPages and that you don't add more than is specified in allPages.

edit:
Figured I would also add why the code you have isn't working.
jQuery.each iterates over every element in an array and you have given it an integer.

Secondly you are for looping over a hard coded number '10' when you should really loop over the length of the array using .length in case you change the array or it is dynamic in the final program.